# can I monitor performance in Azure application after it is deployed (something like profiling)

Tags: performance, azure, profile, monitor

I have a REST api. 
It offers the services get person, get price, get route

how can I determine how long does each call on each of this services take?
For example get person is very fast=ms 5; get route takes 2sec as it needs to make a remote call to Google API.

I could get the time at the beginning of the request and just before the response is submitted, compute the difference and log that to a database. 
But that would be pretty much overhead, so how would you do it? would you do it at all, or just rely on on-machine profiling? what tools would you use that minimize overhead?

What I want is to determine if there is any component that in production could have low availability.

Thank you

Comment: **Yes** You can. Check below mentioned links for more details. [**Azure Monitoring and Using Service Management APIs**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569753/azure-monitoring-and-using-service-management-apis?rq=1) [**performance monitoring in windows azure**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761318/performance-monitoring-in-windows-azure?rq=1) Hope this will help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you want 2 things:

- Minimal impact on your production environment
- Figuring out how much each request takes

In that case I would go for the IIS logs. Windows Azure Diagnostics you can get this out-of-the-box [by adding the module and configuring it](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/#step3). As a result your IIS logs will be stored in your storage account.

After that you can download these logs and use Log Parser to execute some interesting queries which allow you to find the slowest pages, pages with most hits, pages with most exceptions... Log Parser can be a little hard to work with if you never used it before. Take a look at the blog post by Scott Hanselman covering the Log Parser Lizard GUI tool: [Analyze your Web Server Data and be empowered with LogParser and Log Parser Lizard GUI](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnalyzeYourWebServerDataAndBeEmpoweredWithLogParserAndLogParserLizardGUI.aspx):

[image]

This powerful tool can give you all the information you need with minimal impact on your production instances.